# What is the maximum allowed limit on the length of a process name?

Tags: linux, unix, process, procfs

What is the maximum length allowed for a process name? I am reading the process name from `/proc/[pid]/stat` file and i would like to know the maximum buffer that i would need.

I am pretty sure there is a limit which is configurable but just can't find out where this is.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [`man 2 prctl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html):

> PR_SET_NAME (since Linux 2.6.9)
>
> Set the name of the calling thread, using the value in the location pointed to by (char *) arg2.  **The name can be up to 16 bytes long**, and should be null-terminated if it contains fewer bytes.

So I'd go for a **16 bytes** long buffer.

---

#### EDIT:

Let me back this up a little more.

Each process in Linux corresponds to a [`struct task_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched.h#L629) in the kernel, which is defined in `include/linux/sched.h`.

In this definition, there's a field [`char comm[TASK_COMM_LEN]`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched.h#L897), which according to the comment refers to the executable name excluding the path:

```
    char comm[TASK_COMM_LEN]; /* executable name excluding path
                                 - access with [gs]et_task_comm (which lock
                                   it with task_lock())
                                 - initialized normally by setup_new_exec */
```

Its size, `TASK_COMM_LEN`, is defined above in the same header file, [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched.h#L213), to be **16 bytes**:

```
/* Task command name length */
#define TASK_COMM_LEN 16
```

---

Furthermore, quoting LDD3 page 22:

> ...
>
> the following statement prints the process ID and the command name of the current
>   process by accessing certain fields in `struct task_struct` :
>
> ```
> printk(KERN_INFO "The process is \"%s\" (pid %i)\n",
>         current->comm, current->pid);
> ```
>
> The command name stored in `current->comm` is the base name of the program file
>   (**trimmed to 15 characters if need be**) that is being executed by the current process.

Comment: Any idea why the kernel developers thought it would be a good idea to truncate executable names to 16 chars in this day and age?

This impacts `ps -e -o comm` which truncates all process names (e.g. for akonadi resources, which typically have longer executable names).

Comment: Do you know of any warkaround to get the actual command name, even if the program is a bash or python script?

Comment: As of now, this is incorrect. On a modern Arch system for Kernel threads I get things like "kworker/11:0H-events_highpri" which is 28 bytes.